# Python Golf: what's the most concise way of turning this list of lists into a dictionary:

Tags: python, code-golf

I have a list of lists that looks like this:

```
[['Tom', 'Dick'], ['Harry', 'John', 'Mike'], ['Bob']]
```

and I want to turn it into a dictionary where each key is a name and each value is a number corresponding to the position of its sublist in the list:

```
{'Tom': 0, 'Dick': 0, 'Harry': 1, 'John': 1, 'Mike': 1, 'Bob': 2}
```

I tried various list comprehensions, but I couldn't get it to work right with the nested lists. I could use a nested loop, like this:

```
names = [['Tom', 'Dick'], ['Harry', 'John', 'Mike'], ['Bob']]
names_dict = {}
for i, name_sublist in enumerate(names):
    for name in name_sublist:
        names_dict[name] = i
```

but I suspect there is a shorter, more elegant way of doing it.

Comment: The way I remember nesting list comprehensions correctly is that left to right corresponds to shallow to deep in the equivalent nested loop. So to rewrite your loop as a nested comprehension, the outermost loop comes first, then the inner loop. Hope that made some sense :)

Comment: In your question it is implicit that the names are unique. If this is not so, the answers you have got will give the index of the LAST sublist in which a non-unique name appears. The best laid schemas o' Mice an' Men gang aft agley -- assuming 1:1 relationships without checking is a common cause :-)

Comment: Change the last sentence to "not checking for many-to-many relationships is a common cause" :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
names_dict = dict((name,index)
                  for index,lst in enumerate(names)
                  for name in lst)
```

Example:

```
>>> names = [['Tom', 'Dick'], ['Harry', 'John', 'Mike'], ['Bob']]
>>> names_dict = dict((name,index)
...                   for index,lst in enumerate(names)
...                   for name in lst)
>>> names_dict
{'Tom': 0, 'Mike': 1, 'Dick': 0, 'Harry': 1, 'Bob': 2, 'John': 1}
```

Answer (score 19):

Same idea as MizardX, but slightly smaller and prettier in Python 3.0 using [dict comprehensions:](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/)

```
>>> names = [['Tom', 'Dick'], ['Harry', 'John', 'Mike'], ['Bob']]
>>> names_dict = {name:index for index, lst in enumerate(names) for name in lst}
>>> names_dict
{'Tom': 0, 'Mike': 1, 'Dick': 0, 'Harry': 1, 'Bob': 2, 'John': 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

python 2.6

```
dict([(t,l.index(x)) for x in l for t in x])
```

python3.0

```
{t:l.index(x) for x in l for t in x}
```

if l is the list of names